# A Configuration Management Tool that includes version control?

Tags: git, svn, version-control, configuration-management

TL;DR is there any tools that have features for both version controlling and configuration management?

I am completely lost at Configuration management and version control tool, what I can conclude from researching is that version control is just one of the process in SCM (for an analogy, version control is an apple, and fruit is Configuration management). the problem is, there's this question (a legit question from my college assessment) that keeps insisting that they are two same things (apple is version control, and configuration management is a banana, sorry I can't find any other way to explain this but you get the point).

and it tells me that I must pick ONE tool that includes features for BOTH version controlling and configuration management. and so I'm left confused, I wanted to pick either SVN or Git but these two are used only for version controlling, even articles say that "SVN is not a Configuration management tool".

yet when I googled "Top software configuration management tool", all the listed are either "Version control only tools" or "tools that do not include version control" (or at least, none of them mentions that they have version control).

so what gives? is the question that's in the wrong here? or is there something I'm missing? please help me I have never been this confused

Comment: Windows or Linux?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As you said, Configuration Management and Version Control are two different things.

Configuration Management aims to improve the project quality and delivery efficiently, while Version Control aims to manage project versions, and make each version traceable.

And there has many Configuration Management tools which also integrate with Version Control System.

Such as for [Puppet](https://puppet.com/), you can integrate with git version control. And the related links as below:

- [Git Workflow and Puppet Environments](https://puppet.com/blog/git-workflow-and-puppet-environments)
- [Integrating Puppet and Git](https://unix.bris.ac.uk/2015/04/22/integrating-puppet-and-git/)

Or you can use CVS, Ansible etc, all of them are integrate with version control system.

Answer (score -1):

I use puppet along with CVS for version control.A manual step included ( rsync the file changes in cvs repo to puppet directory via a cron ) ,still this works fine for me .